# Android start app at boot after waiting for 1 minute

Tags: android, handler, thread-sleep

I would like to start my app at boot after some time.

I succeed in starting my app at boot. But I would like the app to wait for a minute before starting.

There are two solutions that I have tried (as shown below). Both starts the app but prompts a  "Application Not Responding" (ANR) dialog.

If I modify the time in both solutions to 40000 milliseconds, then no ANR will be prompted.

Does anybody know why? and how can I make the time to 1 minute without any ANR prompts?

Thank you so much!

```
public class StartAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /* SOLUTION 1:
     * final Context con = context; Handler handler = new Handler();
     * handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { Intent i =
     * new Intent(con, MainActivity.class);
     * i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); con.startActivity(i); } },
     * 60000);
     */


            // SOLUTION 2:
    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(60000);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try using Alarm. And skip handling the boot all in all

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler

```
int duration = 1000; // milliseconds

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
public class StartAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /* SOLUTION 1:
     * final Context con = context; Handler handler = new Handler();
     * handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { Intent i =
     * new Intent(con, MainActivity.class);
     * i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); con.startActivity(i); } },
     * 60000);
     */


            // SOLUTION 2:
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @override
        public void run(){
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    (new Thread(runnable)).start();


}
}
```

I am starting a background thread that will launch the intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StartAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
    {
        Context mContext;
        public MyCountDownTimer(Context context, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            mContext.startActivity(i); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {

        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        new MyCountDownTimer(context, 60000, 60000).start(); 
    }

}
```